# d3.js - How to stylize a pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following pie chart:

```js
var data = [12,44,44];

var width = 300,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var piedata = pie(data);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 100)
    .outerRadius(radius - 50);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
    
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(piedata)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", arc);

svg.selectAll("text").data(piedata)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 75);
        return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 30);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 75);
        return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 30);
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.value + '%'; });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The chart data is passed through an array, but how can I pass the color to be used by the chat through the array?

This is my actual array:

```
var data = [12,44,44];
```

But I would like to pass the color of items like this:

```
var data = [
  {
    color: 'red',
    value: 12
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
    value: 44
  },
  {
    color: 'green',
    value: 44
  }
];
```

How do I implement my code to achieve the result below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data structure in your question...

```
var data = [
  {
    color: 'red',
    value: 12
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
    value: 44
  },
  {
    color: 'green',
    value: 44
  }
];
```

... you'll have to, firstly, tell the pie generator the correct property:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value
  })
  .sort(null);
```

That being done, this is the important part: set the `fill` of the paths using the `color` property, that the pie generator puts under the `data` object:

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.data.color
})
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var data = [{
    color: 'red',
    value: 12
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
    value: 44
  },
  {
    color: 'green',
    value: 44
  }
];

var width = 300,
  height = 300,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value
  })
  .sort(null);

var piedata = pie(data);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 100)
  .outerRadius(radius - 50);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(piedata)
  .enter().append("path")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.data.color
  })
  .attr("d", arc);

svg.selectAll("text").data(piedata)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2 - Math.PI / 2;
    d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 75);
    return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 30);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2 - Math.PI / 2;
    d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 75);
    return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 30);
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.value + '%';
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think it will give you the answer.

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["banana", "cherry", "blueberry"])
                                   .range(["#eeff00", "#ff0022", "#2200ff"]);

pie.colors(function(d){ return colorScale(d.fruitType); });
```

or you can directly give

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal().range([/*array of hex values */]);

pie.colors(colorScale);
```

Comment: You should add a bit more explanation of the code you added in the answer